# JavaScript - Animated shapes behave strange in HTML5 <canvas>

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a small univrsity project. I am animating circles using `<canvas>` element. They appear from bottom border and smoothly move up. X coordinate, radius and color of circles are choosen randomly.

The problem is that when my circles reach upper border of `<canvas>` they start to blink and sometimes change their color. Here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Am3Jd/1/). What am i doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `colors[random(0, colors.length)]` is overflowing causing `fillStyle` to overrun

Comment: actually the problem with colors was silly. my `random(start, end)` function generates random numbers from `start` to `end` inclusively, which coused selecting an unexisting element from `colors[]`. so i've changed to `colors[random(0, colors.length-1)]`. works like a charm - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arrustamyan/Am3Jd/3/)

Comment: I thought that was what I said ;)

Comment: Oops my fault! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

`for...in` is great for iterating over objects, but it's not designed for iterating over arrays. In essence, your `i` is jumping around a bit. Instead of using `for...in`, use this (very efficient) loop:

`for(var i = circles.length; i--;) {`

That solves the problem!

Comment: Yes, simpler than mine.

Comment: i've applied the [update](http://jsfiddle.net/arrustamyan/Am3Jd/2/). Yes, it really makes everything work nicely. But i've still noticed a few color changings, but now at the bottom (much more rarly!).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the blinking happens because there are circles on top of other circles. More often, however, it's because you're altering the list while looping through it.

If you instead keep track of the circles to remove, and then remove them *after* drawing the circles, it looks better:

```
function animateCircles() {
    if(frameCounter % 4 === 0) addCircle();
    var remove = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < circles.length; ++i) { // DON'T USE for ... in on an array!
        circles[i]['y'] -= 2;
        drawCircle(circles[i]['x'], circles[i]['y'], circles[i]['r'], circles[i]['c']);
        if(circles[i]['y'] < -circles[i]['r']) remove.push(i);
    }
    for (i = remove.length; --i >= 0; )
        circles.splice(remove[i], 1);
}
```

[Forked fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mjMwC/)

Comment: Thank a lot! It really stopped circles from blinking. Anyway they still sometimes change their colors. Maybe ther's a way to solve this too?

Comment: @Arrustamyan I *think* the color changing may happen when there are circles on top of other ones, but I'm not 100% sure.